# fonts in XML using support library

Tags: android, xml, namespaces

I want to set fonts through XML fron font resource directory ,but in `font.xml` file while using `app:fontStyle` , `app:fontWeight` and `app:font` gadle build fails with error

> /media/shankar/Work
>   Drive/temp/BrainColors/app/src/main/res/font/fonts.xml
>
> Error:attribute 'com.color.brain.braincolors:font' not found
>       Error:attribute 'com.color.brain.braincolors:fontStyle' not found
>       Error:attribute 'com.color.brain.braincolors:fontWeight' not found
>
> Error:/media/shankar/Work Drive/temp/BrainColors/app/src/main/res/font/fonts.xml:0 attribute
>   'com.color.brain.braincolors:font' not found
>       Error:/media/shankar/Work Drive/temp/BrainColors/app/src/main/res/font/fonts.xml:0 attribute
>   'com.color.brain.braincolors:fontWeight' not found
>       Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
>       Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
>       Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>       Failed to execute aapt

i did not understand why this heppens while using `app:` namespace

**fonts.xml**

```
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font android:fontStyle="normal" android:fontWeight="400" android:font="@font/junegull"
        app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/junegull"/>

</font-family>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this tutorial how to use fonts in xml
[fonts-in-xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html)

I think your are missing android Support Library 26.0

Comment: I followed those steps only. but still did not understand causes of error. If you see any error in my xml file suggest me a correction.

Comment: Please read this line   The Support Library 26.0 provides support to the Fonts in XML feature on devices running Android API version 14 and higher.

When you declare font families in XML layout through the support library, use the app namespace.

Note: As of Android Support Library 26.0, you must declare both sets of attributes to ensure your fonts load on devices running Android 8.0 (API level 26) or lower.

Comment: I think your are missing android Support Library 26.0

Comment: yes, thanks a lot, that was the noly mistake, unfortunately i was using 26.0.1-alpha1 i changed it to 26.1.0 and it got solved. Thanks again

Comment: Kindly upvote my answer so its helps other @ChetanShankar